# Finding vital records from Alaska for Native people

Tags: birth-records, alaska

I'm searching for birth records from 1904 in Golovin, Alaska for my Native maternal GF and, approx 1880 in Point Hope, Alaska for my maternal great GF.

I have my grandfather's death cert, as well as his marriage license, but I have not been able to find a birth certificate from 1904, Golovin, Alaska.

On my GF's death cert, it lists his father's name and birthplace, Point Hope, Alaska. but no dates.

My great GF is listed with a Caucasian name. I don't know if he is Caucasian or Native with an "assigned" name. I assume he was born somewhere in the 1880's.